# Struggling with subject to learn(django,game and app development, reverse engineering)

Tags: java, python, django, unity-game-engine

I have been struggling to find a subject to deep study.. the subjects(more like choices)are : django, unity game programming, reverse engineering in assembly and java app developing. I would be happy if someone could light me up at one or more of the subjects from his own experience or recommending me about a new subject of his own(Note:Telling me to try and find out by myself wont help..)
I have knowledge in python,java,C# and little bit of html\css

I have tried unity, java app developing in android studio and I messed with django a little bit.. but every time I started a project I didn't actually finish it.

I am intrested in learning all of them but cant decide which one to start with and I end up learning nothing :v

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I feel that the reason you never finished a project is probably due to lack of motivation. You need to change your focus from "what should I learn" to "what do I want to make". Then find the programming languages/skills that will help you achieve that.

That being said, I think the reverse engineering idea might be out of your scope (at least for now). Obviously, follow your passions and this is just my opinion, but based on the skill set you described (Python, Java, C#, HTML5), I think delving into something like Assembly will feel quite foreign to you (I'm not an expert by any means but I know that people often find Assembly pretty tough).

Since you have some knowledge in Python and HTML5, you could create a web app with Django.

Or, since you know Java and C#, you could go the mobile route - that is, Android with Java or Xamarin with C#.

In terms of Unity, I'd like to advise you, after trying to make games myself, that it takes more than just C# to make a good game. Unless you are either really determined and passionate or are a decent artist and musician as well, you might be frustrated for a while with the games that you make.

For new fields that might interest you, there's always Artificial Intelligence (for which Python is very useful) and Desktop Applications (i.e. Windows Programs with C#, Electron apps with HTML5).

Think back to your unfinished projects; which one was the most fun? Which language did you most enjoy using? This can be an indicator as to where you want to go.

I doubt that people on StackOverflow will (be able to) give you a definitive answer, because we were all in the same place as you once. **I can't decide it for you. Nobody decided it for me.**

> Telling me to find out by myself won't help

It won't help in the short term maybe, but it probably will in the long term.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I could really use your tips! In my unity days i actually made a platform 2d game which was based on free assets.. but i got stuck at the levels design, and as for the "I doubt that people on StackOverflow will be able to give you an answer" I wasn't expecting an answer, I was looking more for the advice of picking one subject